# prepareStatement.executeUpdate(sql) giving error

Tags: java, sql

I don't know why my code is giving error at `executeUpdate(sql)`, when I am trying to update a SQL database using prepared statement. When I try to run the SQL query in Oracle SQL terminal it worked totally fine. Can anyone please help me. I have added code below.

I tried to debug and it is showing error at

```
int iRs = cimStmt.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
```

```
public String updatePatternDiffRemarks(String sLot,
                                   String sRemarks,
                                   String sUserId,
                                   int iLangMode)
    {
        StringBuffer sql        = null;

        Connection con          = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt  = null;


        StringBuffer rtnMsg     = new StringBuffer("");

        try {
            con = CimDbConnect.getDbConnection();
            if (con == null) {
                throw new Exception("Failed DB connect.");
            }
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            sql = new StringBuffer();
            sql.append("   UPDATE ");
            sql.append("   CIM.PRODUCT_BPM_DIFF_COMMENT_TBL ");
            sql.append("   SET REMARKS = ? ");
            sql.append(" , LAST_MODIFIED_DATE = sysdate ");
            sql.append(" , USER_ID = ? ");
            sql.append("   WHERE ");
            sql.append("   LOT_NO = ? ");

            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
            CimPreparedStatement cimStmt = new CimPreparedStatement(stmt);

            int index = 1;
            cimStmt.setString(index++, sRemarks);
            cimStmt.setString(index++, sUserId);
            cimStmt.setString(index++, sLot);

            int iRs = cimStmt.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
            con.commit();

        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            rtnMsg = CimMessage.setMsgStyleCForHtml(rtnMsg, e.getMessage(), false);
            CimMessage.putErrMsgEx(e,  this.getClass().getName() + ": updatePatternDiffRemarks Exception!!");

            if(con != null) {
                try {
                    con.rollback();
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if(stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
                if(con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                CimMessage.putErrMsgEx(e,  this.getClass().getName() + ": updatePatternDiffRemarks Exception!!");
            }
        }
        return rtnMsg.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you get the value of `sql.toString()` just before execute and post here

Comment: Can you show the error ?

Comment: [edit] your question and post the stack trace you are getting.

Comment: You need to use `cimStmt.executeUpdate();` (instead of `cimStmt.executeUpdate(sql.toString())`) don't pass the SQL string again - it's already "stored" in the `PreparedStatement` instance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use separated like this example:

```
public void closeConn(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }
    }

public void updateService(Servs srv){
        String sql = "UPDATE services SET name=?, description =? , content = ? , img =  ? WHERE id = ? ";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try{
            ps = super.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, srv.getName());
            ps.setString(2, srv.getDescription());
            ps.setString(3, srv.getContent());
            ps.setString(4, srv.getImg());
            ps.setInt(5, srv.getId());
            ps.execute();
        }catch(SQLException|NullPointerException e){    
            logger.error("Error UPDATE  >> ",e);
        }
        finally {
            closeCn(ps);
        }
    }// CRUD UPDATE
```